# Struts2 + REST plugin XML output

Tags: rest, struts2, struts

I'm creating a Web Service with the Struts2 REST Plugin, which works great. I just have a problem with the entity names of the XML output.

I have a model class named "ModelClass" in the package "com.mycompany.implementation" with a few properties and a nested class "NestedModelClass", and the XML output looks like:

```
<com.mycompany.implementation.ModelClass>
    ...
    <com.mycompany.implementation.ModelClass_-NestedModelClass>
        ...
    </com.mycompany.implementation.ModelClass_-NestedModelClass>
</com.mycompany.implementation.ModelClass>
```

How can I change the XML Entity name to be displayed without package name - or even a different name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The struts rest plugin uses XStream to serialize your model class to XML. Current versions of XStream support annotating classes and fields to customize the serialization. Unfortunately, the struts rest plugin uses a rather old version of XStream, ignoring those annotations.

The easiest way to get what you want is to write your own ContentTypeHandler and use that instead of the default one provided by the rest plugin. [This blog](http://www.mersoft.com/blog/2009/09/08/struts2-rest-webservice/#xml) describes how to do that.